# How to calculate average weekly hours between 2 dates covering multiple weeks?

Tags: postgresql, datetime

Postgresql 8.4.

I'm new to this concept so if people could teach me I'd appreciate it.

For Obamacare, anyone that works 30 hours per week or more must be offered the same healthcare as is offered to any other worker. We can't afford that so we have to limit work hours for temp and part-timers. This is affecting the whole country.

1. I need to calculate the hours worked (doesn't matter if overtime,
   regular time, double time, etc) between two dates, say Jan 1, 2014,
   and Nov 1, 2014 (Saturday) for each custom week (which beings on Sunday), not the week as defined by Postgresql (which begins on Monday).
2. Each of my custom work weeks begins on Sunday and ends on Saturday.
3. I don't know if I have to include weeks where
   they did not work at all in the average, but let's assume I do. Zero hours that week would draw down the average.
4. Table name is 'employeetime', date field is 'employeetime.stopdate', hours worked per day is in the field 'employeetime.hours', employeeid field is 'employeetime.empid'.
5. I'd prefer to do this in one query per employee and I will execute the query once per employee as I loop through employees. If not I'm open to suggestions. But I'd like to understand the SQL presented in the answer.
6. Currently `EXTRACT(week from '2014-01-01')` calculates the start of the week as a Monday, so that doesn't work for me. [Link here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

How would I do that without doing, say a separate query for each week, per person? We have 200 people to process.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have set up a table to match your format:

```
select * from employeetime order by date;

id date       hours
1  2014-11-06 10
1  2014-11-07 3
1  2014-11-08 5
1  2014-11-09 3
1  2014-11-10 5
```

You can get the week starting on Sunday by shifting. Note, here the 9th is a Sunday, so that is where we want the boundary.

```
select *, extract(week from date + '1 day'::interval) as week
from employeetime
order by week;

id date       hours week
1  2014-11-07 3     45
1  2014-11-06 10    45
1  2014-11-08 5     45
1  2014-11-09 3     46
1  2014-11-10 5     46
```

And now the week shifts on Sunday rather than Monday. From here, the query to get hours by week/employee would be simple:

```
select id, sum(hours) as hours, extract(week from date + '1 day'::interval) as week 
from employeetime 
group by id, week
order by id, week;

id hours week
1  18    45
1  8     46
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. Looks like it works! Just curious why you added 1 day to the week, instead of subtracting one day.

Comment: @Bulrush adding one day to Sunday shifts it to the week crossing. Were I to subtract a day, the week start would have been Tuesday.